# Need to find out how to make a button go out

Tags: javascript, countdown

currently, I have a countdown script that counts down to 15.

```
 <div id="skip" style="margin-top: 4px;">
            <p> Please wait for <span id="timer" style="font-weight:bold;">15</span> seconds</p>
        </div>

<div id="button">
        <form action="http://website.com">
    <input type="submit" style="display: none;" value="Go to website"/>

    <script>
    var count = 15;

    function countDown(){
        var timer = document.getElementById("timer");
        if(count > 0){
            count--;
            timer.innerHTML = count;
            setTimeout("countDown()", 1000);
        }else{
            document.getElementById("button");

        }
    }
    countDown();
    </script>
```

It does it's job and counts down to fifteen. What I actually want to happen is that when the 15 seconds is up, it will instead show a button that says "Go to website".

Basically it's like other shortener but it's not.

I don't think document.getElementByID doesnt work. I've been looking for a way to make the button appear but it's not working.

Comment: Well, since you used `display: none` to hide it did you try `display: block` or something else to show it?

Comment: I want it to appear at the same place where the counter is, if I use display: block, it's already in the page together with the counter.

Comment: Basically what I would want to happen is when the counter runs out, the button takes it place.

Comment: Then remove the button initially, when timer is out grab the element that has your counter and set its `innerHTML` to whatever you would have written for the button originally.

Comment: I know this isn't relevant, but it bothers me:  you're counting down **from** 15 to zero, not to 15.

Answer (score 0):

Start with the button hidden, and remove that condition when the timer expires. A common way to do that is to use a "hidden" utility class, as shown below.

*Note: Count in this snippet is 3, because I get bored waiting for 15 seconds each iteration. :)*

```js
var count = 3;

function countDown(){
  var timer = document.getElementById("timer");
  var button;
  var skipContainer;
  if(count > 0){
    count--;
    timer.innerHTML = count;
    setTimeout("countDown()", 1000);
  }else{
    skipContainer = document.getElementById("skip");
    button = document.getElementById("button");
    skipContainer.classList.add("hidden");
    button.classList.remove("hidden");
  }
}
countDown();
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="skip" style="margin-top: 4px;">
  <p> Please wait for <span id="timer" style="font-weight:bold;">15</span> seconds</p>
</div>

<div id="button" class="hidden">
  <form action="http://website.com">
  <input type="submit" value="Go to website"/>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use setInterval() function that I think is more natural for the count down process. I reuse most code from @Palpatim answer.

```js
var count = 3;

var myVar = setInterval(function(){ countDown() }, 1000);

function countDown() {
    var timer = document.getElementById("timer");
  var button;
  var skipContainer;
  if(count > 0){
    count--;
    timer.innerHTML = count;    
  }else{
    myStopFunction();
    skipContainer = document.getElementById("skip");
    button = document.getElementById("button");
    skipContainer.classList.add("hidden");
    button.classList.remove("hidden");
  }
}

function myStopFunction() {
    clearInterval(myVar);
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="skip" style="margin-top: 4px;">
  <p> Please wait for <span id="timer" style="font-weight:bold;">15</span> seconds</p>
</div>

<div id="button" class="hidden">
  <form action="http://website.com">
  <input type="submit" value="Go to website"/>
  </form>
</div>
```